# How do I set switches normally defined in app.config in the C# Interactive window?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, roslyn

I'm trying to load a DLL with the C# Interactive REPL (from Roslyn). It throws the following exception:

> "An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which
>   would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of
>   the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable
>   CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is
>   not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the
>   loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information."

The DLL is not on a network location, so I don't know why this exception is being thrown. Regardless, there is no app.config file for me to modify (to my knowledge), so does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

UPDATE:

I've [unblocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the assembly, which makes this exception go away. But I'd still like to answer the more general question of how do I set switches normally defined in app.config in the C# Interactive window?

Comment: This is especially useful in cases where you are working with black box components which encapsulate some EF implementation, and where the only way of setting connection strings is via config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly in question doesn't need to be on a network location at the time you try to load it. The message you're seeing is warning you that the assembly you are trying to load was (at some point) downloaded from the internet and is currently marked as untrusted.

To your meta-question, most config settings map to one or more code constructs (API's, attributes, etc.) that allow you to programmatically adjust the settings to your needs. How to modify particular settings depends on the setting and the API it affects. In some cases, you might need to write code to configure the runtime, in others you might have to configure IIS, logging and tracing, WCF endpoints, etc.

If you read the article linked to above, you'll find the following:

> If an application has been copied from the web, it is flagged by Windows as being a web application, even if it resides on the local computer. You can change that designation by changing the file properties, or you can use the  element to grant the assembly full trust. As an alternative, you can use the [UnsafeLoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.unsafeloadfrom%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to load a local assembly that the operating system has flagged as having been loaded from the web.

Using UnsafeLoadFrom may be safer in general than enabling your app to download any arbitrary assembly from an untrusted source and have it run with full trust inside your app.

The docs go on to say:

> This element is typically used in the application configuration file, but can be used in other configuration files depending upon the context. For more information, see the article More Implicit [Uses of CAS Policy: loadFromRemoteSources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/06/08/more-implicit-uses-of-cas-policy-loadfromremotesources.aspx) in the .NET Security blog.

Read this latter document carefully - it illustrates the code you need to write to effect the same outcome as setting the loadFromRemoteSources config flag: HOWEVER, don't underestimate the dangers of loading arbitrary code into your apps!

Comment: I was hoping there might be some `bool` on some Environment object or something similar; I think it's unfortunate that mimicking the behavior of app.config can be non-intuitive.

Comment: That wouldn't really work unless you were to configure (potentially hundreds) of independent environment variables and values independently for every app you run. Config files give you a declarative way to control a large number of switches, dials and knobs for a colossal range of features and subsystems. by necessity, effecting the same changes via code alone will require some work.